# Need to update primary email address in Exchange 2010 based on email address policy

Tags: exchange-2010

An email address for one of my end users was incorrectly configured awhile back in Exchange 2010.

When I go into the properties of the user in the Exchange Management Console I can only change the primary email address if I clear the checkbox for "Automatically update e-mail addresses based on e-mail address policy".

Based on this it seems as though I need to change the primary email address for the user somewhere else besides the properties of that specific user.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can handle this.  The easiest fix is as you suggested.  Uncheck the "Automatically update e-mail addresses based on e-mail address policy" box and then manually configure the address as you see fit.  This has some drawbacks however.  It's sloppy and you're not really fixing the issue, you're just working around it.  To truly fix it you'll need to look at your email address policy(cies) and determine why this specific user is not being affected by it.  Usually it is some aspect of the user account/mailbox that isn't triggering the rules of the email address policy in some way.

To check your email policy, load up the Exchange Management Console.  Navigate to Organizational Configuration.  Then choose the Hub Transport section.  Within that section you should see an "E-mail Address Policies" tab.  All of your policies should be listed there.

Comment: I might add: This is usually because of middle names. Imagine someone named "Billy Gates Andersen".. his e-mail address would (with the most common policy) be BillyGates.Andersen@company.TLD. Most people would prefer Billy.Gates.Andersen@company.TLD

Comment: Can you point me to where that email policy would be located? Thanks for your help. Will award the answer as soon as I verify that it works.

Comment: Answer edited above.

Comment: Thanks for following up even after I awarded the check...I appreciate you being thorough.